# fetching the complete URL in angular2

Tags: angular

How could i get the complete set of URL? like for eg

http://localhost:4200/#/resetPasswordEmail, while using the suggestions provided above, I'm only getting the #/resetPasswordEmail.

I would like the get the complete URL path right from http://localhost:4200/#/resetPasswordEmail

Is that possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you don't need angular for this: just use

`document.URL`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @FeMachine. I got what I wanted. :)